# Return a piece of an array after finding the highest integer in java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, integer

So after working on finding the highest sum of any given amount of credit card numbers I realized I dug myself into a bit of a hole. (currently using 3 cards "123-123, 234-234 and 345-345" as test numbers.) After writing this out:

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)

var sumpre = [];

for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  var eXt = arr[i];
  eXt = eXt.replace (/-/g, "");
     for (var j = 0; j < eXt.length; j++) {
     sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(j, 1)); 
    }
  sumpre.push(sum);
}
console.log(sumpre);

var highest = sumpre[0];

for (var i=1; i<=sumpre.length; i++){
  if (sumpre[i]>highest){
    highest=sumpre[i];
  }
}

console.log(highest)
```

Which works to find the highest sum, however; I need it to return the card number with the highest sum in its original form at the end and am not sure what method would be best to get back to that or if I should reformat it from the start.

Comment: For minimal changes to your current code, you could use `highest` to keep the index of the array item with the highest value, instead of keeping the actual value itself - then you could retrieve the original card value via that index. (As an aside, `eXt.substr(j, 1)` can be simplified to `eXt.charAt(j)` or just `eXt[j]`.)

Comment: Haven't looked at your code too carefully but shouldn't arr[highest] return the original card number?

Comment: thanks both I'll look back through it with these in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, or as shown in [Gerardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40353102/615754), one way to do it with minimal changes to your current code is to use `highest` to keep the index of the array item with the highest value, instead of keeping the actual value itself - then you could retrieve the original card value via that index.

But for fun, here's another way to do it:

```js
function sumDigitsInString(s) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(s, function(p, c) { return p + (+c || 0); }, 0);
}

function itemWithLargestSum(a) {
  return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
    var sum = sumDigitsInString(c);
    return p[0] > sum ? p : [sum, c];
  }, [0])[1];
}

// given an array of strings:
var input = ["123-123", "234-234", "345-345", "111-111"];
var largest = itemWithLargestSum(input);
console.log(largest);
```

Further reading:

- [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [Array `.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())
- [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())
- [`?:` (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado. I linked to your answer because it showed clearly what the OP needed to change, and I think OP was right to accept it. My answer wasn't really intended to be thorough enough to be the accepted answer: I thought I'd show some ideas for implementing the different parts of the problem without actually explaining, leaving it to any curious readers to figure it out for themselves using the links I included.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this, just with Array methods.

```js
var inputCards = ["989-000", "123-999", "456-456"];
var sum = 0,
  sumNumbers = {},
  maxVal = 0;


inputCards.map(function(num) {
  var replaceText = new RegExp(/-/g);
  var number = num.replace(replaceText, "").split("");

  var prevVal = 0;
  sumNumbers[num] = number.reduce((prevVal, currentVal) =>
    parseInt(prevVal, 10) + parseInt(currentVal, 10));
});


console.log(Object.keys(sumNumbers).reduce((maxVal, currentVal) =>
  sumNumbers[maxVal] > sumNumbers[currentVal] ? maxVal : currentVal));
```